# Laravel Migration: Add a column with a default value of an existing column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

i need to add a last_activity column on a table of a live site where i have to make it's default value to equal of updated_at column value. I'm using laravel 5.1 and mysql database driver.

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->dateTime('last_activity')->default("COLUMN VALUE OF UPDATED_AT");
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This should work:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dateTime('last_activity');
});

\DB::statement('UPDATE users SET last_activity = updated_at');
```

See "Running a General Statement": https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions

To enforce this relationship when a `User` is created or updated, you can use [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) and/or [Model Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers).

Comment: If you use `$table->timestamp('last_activity')->useCurrent();` it'd continue to set last_activity whenever the row is updated.